# Does anyone know what "HF-LPBX300 Image" is?

Tags: binary, reverse-engineering, firmware

I have a Deye Sun 600 Inverter and I am not very satisfied with the monitoring capabilities. It seems like there are a fairly high delay for measurements written to the registers. Anyway I want to Reverse Engineer the firmware and wanted to start using binwalk. However there is nothing so I tried using "strings" and there is only one useable string which is the text in my title "HF-LPBX300 Image". Does anyone know what this means? Is this something like an encryption algorithm or a specific binary image format?

Useful Information:

- Bin File: Deye Sun 600 Firmware V.1.53 (http://47.254.36.66/0_D0002_18/MW3_16U_5406_1.53.bin)
- Deye doesn't want to send any information or the firmware as editable code

Answer (score 1):

I'm also interested in the same issue.

As far as I found out, the Deye micro inverters use electronics from Hi-Flying.com.

Edit:

This has the same "HF-LPBX300 Image" in the firmware:

- http://www.hi-flying.com/wi-fi-iot/wi-fi-serial-module/wport-w30
- http://www.hi-flying.com/download-center-1/firmware-1/download-item-pw11-pw12-pw10-ew10-ew11-ew12-hf2211s-w30-pwa1-firmware

Edit2: The actual "payload" of the firmware bin starts at file position 0x100 as an lzma packed archive.

Comment: This is not a answer

Comment: I am quite sorry that I can't provide an answer. Do you think your comment was helpful? Do you have an answer? Maybe a clue at this stage, where nobody has a proper answer, _can_be_ helpful to go the right direction on finding out...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an image for the HF-LPX30 Series Low Power WiFi Module, indeed from Hi-Flying:
https://www.micros.com.pl/mediaserver/RF_HF-LPT230-1_0002.pdf
Looking into that description shows configuration web pages (e.g. p54) that are identical to the Deye device. Downloading the firmware from here:
http://www.hi-flying.com/download-center-1/firmware-1/download-item-hf-lpx30-firmware shows the head of the upgrade images is exactly what you see:

```
birger@AMDDesktop:~/Downloads$ hd LPB130_UPGRADE_HFV4.13.35_2MB_20221222.bin|head
00000000  48 46 2d 4c 50 42 58 33  30 30 20 49 6d 61 67 65  |HF-LPBX300 Image|
```

Taking out the big gun in the form of ghidra also shows the image's language is ARM Cortex (little endian) as for the HF-LPX30 architecture and not MIPS as is it would be for the wport-w30 according to it's datasheet.